# cakephp compare password for webservice

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm new to cakephp, I'm implementing a web service for update password where user will provide oldpassword, newpassword, username parametrs, I have to check in db if that username has the old password, then update db with newpassword.

what I have done so far is, I got the parametrs, I can fetch the data with username like this

```
 $username = $this->request->query['username'];
 $oldpassword = $this->request->query['oldpassword'];
 $dataexist = $this->User->find('first', array('fields' => array('User.id','User.username','User.password'), 'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username)));
```

Now its returning data, but if I use password field like this

```
$dataexist = $this->User->find('first', array('fields' => array('User.id','User.username','User.password'), 'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username,'User.password' => $oldpassword)));
```

Its returning empty result, even I pass correct old password..!
where I'm doing mistake, any help is much appreciated...

Comment: The password in the database is encrypted. The password the user puts is in plain text. You will have to first encrypt the old password to compare properly.

Comment: How can I do that ? I mean which encryption ? I'm new to cakephp

Comment: I think the method is Security::hash. https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html

Comment: Ok so I need your help, I know these two things from config file, "Security.salt" and "Security.cipherSeed", How can I encrypt plain password now ?

Comment: Well, I don't know how you are hashing the passwords in the first place. When you are creating an user, how do you hash the passwords? Are you following some tutorial or something like that?

Comment: Could you provide you `CakePHP` version and The `Auth` configuarion of your App

Comment: I m using cakephp 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am assuming here that you are using the default password Hasher,

Share your auth configuration to change that assumption :)

If it's the case, you can get the hash password like this

```
<?php

App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
$hashPassword = $passwordHasher->hash($rawPassword);


?>
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it's quite similar to the solution I found.  Actually I'm working on a project that is already partially implemented. They have used blowfishpassword hasher for cakephp. You can see it here https://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-BlowfishPasswordHasher.html
I got the solution by using check() method of BlowfishPasswordHasher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code :

```
$newPass = '123abc';
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array(
'User.id' => AuthComponent::user('id')
),
'fields' => array('password')
));
$storedHash = $user['User']['password'];
$newHash = Security::hash($newPass, 'blowfish', $storedHash);
if($storedHash == $newHash){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already implemented exactly the same way you mentioned.